# Difference between "and" function in Python when using nested if-statements

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, arguments, cs50

The program im writing tests different requirements for a vanity plate and returns True if all the reqs are met and else it returns False (CS50P) and its working how it should work but I have a question about the difference in the use of the and function in python when checking two statements in an if-clause. I know i could have used early return statements and I have already adjusted the code but I still want to know why it returns True when i put the statement to test if the char is inequal to 0 one if statement below since the char variable doesnt get changed and it should return True anyways.

This is the working code:

```py
def main():
    plate = input("Plate: ")
    if is_valid(plate) == True:
        print("Valid")
    else:
        print("Invalid")

def is_valid(plate):
    if plate[0:2].isalpha():
        if 2 <= len(plate) <= 6:
            if plate.isalnum():
                for char in plate:
                    if char.isdigit():
                        position = plate.index(char)
                        if plate[position:].isdigit() and char != "0":
                            return True
                        else:
                            return False
                return True

main()
```

This satisfies all criteria and works fine:

Input: ABC123
Output: Valid! (True)
Input: ABC012
Output: Invalid! (False)
...

However this does not work:

```py
def main():
    plate = input("Plate: ")
    if is_valid(plate) == True:
        print("Valid")
    else:
        print("Invalid")

def is_valid(plate):
    if plate[0:2].isalpha():
        if 2 <= len(plate) <= 6:
            if plate.isalnum():
                for char in plate:
                    if char.isdigit() and char != "0":
                        position = plate.index(char)
                        if plate[position:].isdigit():
                            return True
                        else:
                            return False
                return True

main()
```

For some reason, when i move the and char statement one if statement up the I/O is suddenly:
Input: ABC123
Output: Valid! (True)
Input: ABC012
Output: Valid! (True)

Comment: It's doing exactly what you told it to do.  It ignores every "0" in the string, treating it as if it's not a digit.

Comment: There's no `return` at the outer level of the code, so if you fail one of the first couple of `if`s you'll implicitly return `None`.  Is that what you want?

Comment: I'm curious, what does the first function return if you input `ABC102`?

Comment: It outputs Valid / returns True, just as it should. I dont understand why it is ignoring every "0" in the string. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Consider the case where `char=='0'` and `plate[position:].isdigit() is True`. Can you see why in function 1, the result is to return False, but in function 2 the result is to continue looping?

Comment: because in function 2, if char=="0", it wouldnt even enter the first if-statement?

Comment: Right, exactly!

Comment: damn, it makes sense now, thank you!!

Comment: `position = plate.index(char)` will not do what you want if there are duplicate characters in the plate. It will set `position` to the index of the first occurrence, not the current one. Use `enumerate()` when iterating over the characters so you always get the current position.